# const void *pString to string

Tags: c++, c

I have `const void  *pString` which is a Pointer to the string to analyze. Assume it hold a value ABCD, I want to get the string ABCD from it, can someone help ? 
When I try to use `char *ptr = (char *) pString;` then use
`ptr[0]` it gives A
`ptr[1]` it gives empty
`ptr[2]` it gives B
`ptr[3]` it gives empty and so on.

Comment: Looks like `pString` is a [wide string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character)?

Comment: please specify your hardware platform, compiler toolchain and operating system.

Comment: pString is received from this API https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368566(v=vs.85).aspx . As per msdn document it just says its pointer to string which can be unicode or character set from ANSI.

Comment: By definition, you can't _receive_ a string from this API (at least not on this parameter). It is defined as input and the function signature promises not to change it. Whatever you put there will be the same as it was before after the function call. So basically it's you who should know what it is.

Comment: @ArunKumarM are you, by chance, hooking this function? if so, the `iCharset` parameter tells you what format the `pString` data is using: "*`iCharset` [in]
Character set descriptor. **If the input string is an ANSI string, this descriptor is set to the character set identifier. If the string is a Unicode string, this descriptor is set to -1**.*"

Answer (score 0):

Use WCHAR string for ScriptStringAnalyse(),

then

```
...
wstring ws(...);
string str(ws.begin(), ws.end());
...
str[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

WCHAR helped out here and I was able to get the output using the below snippet:

```
const WCHAR *ptr = (const WCHAR *)pString;
char *pmbbuf = (char*) malloc(len + 1);

if (pmbbuf != NULL) {
    wcstombs(pmbbuf, (LPCWSTR) ptr, len);
    string str = string(pmbbuf);
}
```